# remove BBcode tags from whole match

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all

How can I get Array with all string.

```
$str = "This is some a text with [b]Bold[/b] and [i]Italic[/i] elements inside";

preg_match_all("/.*(\[.+\]).*/isU",$str,$matches);

print_r($matches);
```

I obtain only:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => This is a text with [b]
            [1] => Bold[/b]
            [2] =>  and [i]
            [3] => Italic[/i]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => [b]
            [1] => [/b]
            [2] => [i]
            [3] => [/i]
        )

)
```

without "elements inside" text in the end.

Comment: show how should look the ideal/expected result for you

Answer (score 0):

Preg_replace?

```
$new_str = preg_replace("/(\[.*?\])/", "", $str);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fKH